# How to find main menus controls on safari in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Java.  I have an issue: when I click on menu button, the menu control is notfound in safari browser.  How do I solve it?

Comment: HTML code <span> 見積もり/ご注文</span> these for Main menu                  <a href="http://50.62.138.41/crimsoncswebqa/ServiceSelectionPage.aspx?qid=4vDT9NxX42gLvlHHzPagNkXAhmAnl6jgZTgQyDOeCDPFdEQpfh6tqfYNt86N7b5P"> ≫ お見積もり/ご注文</a> these for sub menu

Answer (score 0):

- For this problem you have to use short cuts.
- For example you need to open FILE menu then you have a short cut "ALT+F"
- You can do this with Actions class in Selenium web driver.
- Example:

  ```
  new Actions(driver)
      .keyDown(Keys.ALT)
      .sendKeys("F")
      .keyUp(Keys.ALT)
      .perform();
  ```
- Here I have use ALT + F key to open menu.
- Your problem is solve easily by this code.

===============================================================

Note : If there is bug or defect in Safari Menu then This will not work properly. So please check it manually first then apply automation on that.Save time. :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. but how I locate that menu elements? I tried with action commands buts its give me error as " Unknown command: {"id":"lxgnnw4thmv2","name":"sendKeysToActiveElement","parameters":{"value":["?"]}}"

Comment: What is your final goal? Can you write down step for me? So i can give perfect solution.

Comment: I have to automate Inquiry Form, there are some main menus buttons that I have to click & then select sub-menu but in safari my main menu controls are not found, which is working fine in IE,Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: As I understand your step, You have web app which have menu. Correct me if i m wrong. Can you share working code for that menu selection ? so I can check for safari.

Comment: Thread.sleep(10000);
  w.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navigationContainer']/div/div/div/ul[1]/li[2]/a/span")).click();
  w.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navigationContainer']/div/div/div/ul[1]/li[2]/ul/li/a")).click(); I use these code for find menu elements. first line code is for Main menu & second is for sub menu. its on Home page after click on Sub menu Inquiry form will open.

Comment: Please also update HTML code in question. So anyone can answer.

Comment: I think it is not related to custom menu in browser. It is application element. So please share HTML code also. If your element are not visible in safari then we have to check.

Comment: HTML code <span> 見積もり/ご注文</span> these for Main menu                  <a href="http://50.62.138.41/crimsoncswebqa/ServiceSelectionPage.aspx?qid=4vDT9NxX42gLvlHHzPagNkXAhmAnl6jgZTgQyDOeCDPFdEQpfh6tqfYNt86N7b5P"> ≫ お見積もり/ご注文</a> these for sub menu

Comment: As I know this is not a problem of browser. This is problem of safari driver. You have to update it. Then If any exception is come , comment me.